# Error while mounting samba share: CIFS VFS: No username specified

Tags: mount, samba

I'm trying to mount a samba share on CentOS, Ubuntu and Debian and I'm getting the error "CIFS VFS: No username specified" although everything seems fine.

Here's my /etc/fstab :

```
//1.2.3.4/share  /mnt/share  cifs rw,iocharset=utf8,uid=root,gid=root,credentials=/root/smbcredentials   0   0
```

my /root/smbcredentials

```
username=...
password=...
```

and my output:

```
# mount  /mnt/backups
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //10.13.37.5/backups,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
# dmesg | tail 
[ 1308.670814] CIFS VFS: No username specified
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to install `cifs-utils`:

```
 yum install cifs-utils # centos/redhat/older fedora
 dnf install cifs-utils # newer fedora
 apt install cifs-utils # debian/ubuntu
```